# How do I solve postgresql error "connection attempt failed"?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I wanted to build my springboot project. Then I want to dockerize my code. But when I built, I got error. I think this occured caused by postgresql setting. But I could not find reason.

Could you please help me?

```
docker-compose.yml file;

version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  db:
    container_name: productdb
    image: postgres:9.5
    volumes:
    - sample_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=bright
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=productdb
    - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  productdb: {}
```

application.yml file;

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
  registerWithEureka: false
  fetchRegistry: false
  server:
  enableSelfPreservation: false
  waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0

spring:
  application:
    name: product-service
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/productdb
    username: postgres
    password: xxxx
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Error looks like;

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

Thank you

Comment: Is the 'web' container hosting your spring app? If yes, can you ping from inside your web container to the postgresql container?

Comment: Yes my app is web container. But i could not ping to postgresql container. When I used jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/productdb in application.yml then I can build successfully but then when I wanted to run docker, following error occured.  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused

Comment: You don't need to connect with localhost, (localhost = container itself, you need to connect with the container name of the postgres container when you want to connect from another container;

Comment: lvthillo, yeah I know. That is why I ve changed localhost. Now I am using as above. But when I wanted to clean-install mvn package, I ve got error "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed."

Answer (score 5):

If your docker-compose.yml file is well configured, it should be start two containers:

```
docker ps
```

[image: docker ps]
source: https://intelligentbee.com/2017/09/18/setup-docker-symfony-project/

One for app and one for db.

These containers are in the same host, so if your web need to connect to the database, you must the ip instead : localhost, 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0

You cat get  the ip with this

```
hostname -I| awk '{printf $1}'
```

If your web and your database would be in different host, you can use the public ip where is hosted the database. But as you are using **docker-compose** this is not the case.

I suggest you to test if your database is ready and available, before using it in your web app.

In order to test your database , You can following one of these approaches:

---

## Check db status with telnet

There are several way , but the easiest option is the **telnet** command. For instance, in order to test if mysql container is ready to use in the same machine where was started:

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

If your mysql is ready, telnet must show you a result like the following picture:

[image: telnet ok mysql]

Any other negative result, would indicate that your mysql container is exited or wrong.

**Note:Change 3306 for the correct postgress port**

---

## Check db status with Database IDE

Other option for UI users is testing the database connection using some Database IDE. Just download one of the several postgress client IDEs and testing your database.

---

## Don't hardcode parameters

It is a good practice to externalize configuration using environment variables. Spring and docker **know** and allow us to use them.

So, modify your **application.yml** :

From

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/productdb
```

To

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:5432/productdb
```

For **development**, in your eclipse use [run as configurations  >> environment section](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/eclipse/eclipse-env.png)

For **production** you can:

- export variable before **run**
- pass it to your docker run sentence...

```
docker run -d \
--name my_funny_api \
-p 8080:8080 \
-e "DATABASE_HOST=10.10.01.52" \
-i -t my_funny_api_image
```

or

```
export HOST_IP=$(hostname -I| awk '{printf $1}')

docker run -d \
--name my_funny_api \
-p 8080:8080 \
-e "DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}" \
-i -t my_funny_api_image
```

- Finally to avoid manually task to manage your variables, you can use : http://github.com/jrichardsz/tachikoma-ops

Comment: JRichardsz, Before running on docker when I try to build I got "attemption failed" error.

Comment: Do you mean when you execute : mvn clean package?

Comment: mvn clean package,  does not start the app. Just compile it. Could you attach the entire fail log? Maybe is a unit test error.

Answer (score 1):

Using DataGrip software and DB in DigitalOcean. Got error

> `[08001] The connection attempt failed. java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.`

Made sure my current IP was one of the [allowed inbound connections](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to/secure/) and that worked. (Even though the error should probably have been different.)

Hope this is useful to someone eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB should accept connections outside of the container

`sudo docker run --name pg -p 5432:5432 -v pg_data:/var/lib/postgres/data -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=pg_user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pg_password -d postgres -c "listen_addresses=*"`

*"listen_addresses=*" It will accept connection outside of the container*

You can use follow credential to connect your spring boot project

db_user=pg_user

db_password=pg_password

db_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb